# how can I read xls and xlsx file in spark with java?

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, rdd, apache-spark-sql

I want to read xls and xlsx (MS Excel) files row by row in spark like we do it for text files OR any how?

I want to use spark to increase performance for reading a large xls file say 1 GB, that's why I need spark to read the file in parts like we do for text files.

How can I read data from excel files in spark whether it is line by line or not?

I just want to read entries in the xls file anyhow using spark.

Please suggest.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not do that with `spark` . It is not meant for it. Use someother library e.g. [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) to read excel and then feed that data to spark as text.

Comment: Thanks for your answer..I want to ask, if we can not read data directly from excel and we have to read it using simple java than how performance could increase, as I am first reading using java and then processing it with spark? we have to do it for really big files as I have mentioned?

Comment: Yes problem is Excel but on the flip side you are only reading it using external library not processing it. Reading even big files is not going to be super expensive compared to processing. Think of it as a datasource if your data was in a database you would had to read it first before processing it. You could use multithreads to read as well if you must but even for few hundred gigs you  should still be able to read and feed simultaneously .

Comment: Hi. It's now 2017 and I found this library. It might help. Cheers!

https://github.com/crealytics/spark-excel

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I done.

In maven add dependencies

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.crealytics</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-excel_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

My main class

```
import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

public class ReadExcelSheets {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //skip logging extras
        Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR);

       //build session
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                .builder()
                .appName("Java Spark SQL Example")
                .config("spark.master", "local")
                .getOrCreate();

        //read excel - change file name
        Dataset<Row> df = spark.read()
                .format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
                .option("useHeader", "true")
                //.option("dataAddress", "'Sheet1'!A1:M1470") // optional when you want to read sheets where A1 first top cell and M1470 us very bottom left of sheet.
                .load("datasets/test1.xlsx");
        //show your data
        df.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Though the question is bit old, i am still answering it. May be it will be useful to someone else.
The answer is yes you can do it with apache spark 2.x. Let say you want to convert a xls with 3 columns to Dataset.

```
  class Bean {
     private String col1;
     private String col2;   
     private Timestamp col3;
}

StructType structType= new StructType(new StructField[] {
                new StructField("col1", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty()),
                new StructField("col2", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty()),
                new StructField("col3", DataTypes.TimestampType, true, Metadata.empty())
        });

Dataset<Bean> ds = sparkSession.read().
                schema(structType).
                format("com.crealytics.spark.excel").
                option("useHeader", true). // If the xls file has headers
                option("timestampFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"). // If you want to convert timestamp to a specific format
                option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "false").
                option("inferSchema", "false").
                option("addColorColumns", "false").
                load("/home/user/test/sample.xls"). //path to xls or xlsx
                as(Encoders.bean(Bean.class)); // Bean in which you want to convert the data, you can remove this line if Dataset<Row> is just fine for you
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the HadoopOffice library to read/write Excel files with Spark (https://github.com/ZuInnoTe/hadoopoffice/wiki). It supports encrypted Excel, linked workbooks, filtering by metadata ...